# Let's encrypt certificates fail to verify, throw errors in a Node.js web app

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2016, openssl, certbot

I've recently started getting issues with my Let's Encrypt certificates.

On the web browser I don't get any issues for the certificate, but when I run an Java web app thru NGINX using the certificate and I try to connect using `axios` npm package from a Node.js web app I keep getting certificate validation errors.

I've tried verifying using the following commands and I get the following outputs:

```
openssl verify -CAfile C:\Certbot\live\example.org\fullchain.pem  C:\Certbot\live\example.org\cert.pem
C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
error 2 at 2 depth lookup: unable to get issuer certificate
openssl verify -untrusted C:\Certbot\live\example.org\chain.pem  C:\Certbot\live\example.org\cert.pem
C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
error 20 at 2 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I've even downloaded the ISRG Root X1 intermediate certificate and added it to the Certificate Store on my Windows Server 2016...

Comment: Unless you/whoever overrode it when obtaining the cert, LetsEncrypt [for now defaults to a 'compatibility' chain that still bridges to DST Root X3](https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html) (see the green arrows). That's why your commandline `openssl verify` fails. However, openssl except for broken 1.0.x, and thus nonancient nodejs, will succeed if you give it a truststore containing the _root_ cert for ISRG X1 not the cross cert. For direct nodejs this is usually the default but depending on your coding there may be many different ways; ...

Comment: ... for axios I don't know and don't see anything relevant in the doc on npmjs. I also don't know what you mean by "ISRG Root X1 intermediate" -- the ISRG intermediate is R3 or E1 (for now), and if you mean the _cross_ cert you already had that in your fullchain.pem file and don't need to download anything. But in any case nodejs does not use the Windows cert store at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are missing the intermediate certificate in the Nginx configuration. You need to append it after the host certificate.

Comment: I tried what you suggested like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965546 but I still get the same error :/

Comment: Huh weird after a restart it fixed it. Weird, because it's not how it should be defined in my opinion, since fullchain.pem was already defined elsewhere but as long as it works I guess